Regex pattern in sed to match hexadecimal address of fixed length
I would like to match a hexadecimal address of fixed length using a regex pattern in sed. For example:
0x000000010b2e993c
0x is always present followed by the sixteen-character hexadecimal number. This is successful:
's/0x[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]//'

Is there a shorthand way to match whereby I can use 0x then [0-9a-f] occurring sixteen times?

Thanks @AdminBee. I tried a variation on that answer and it works nicely: 's/0x[0-9a-f]\{16\}//'
That said, I think Stéphane's answer below is better still. Will accept.

sed 's/0[xX][[:xdigit:]]\{16\}//g'

Is standard syntax with basic regexps.
Most sed implementations now support a -E option to switch to extended regexps¹:
sed -E 's/0[xX][[:xdigit:]]{16}//g'

[[:xdigit:]] would be the equivalent of [0123456789abcdefABCDEF] (not necessarily [0-9a-fA-F] which could match hundreds of other characters which happen to sort between 0 and 9, a and f or A and F).
In any case, note that 0x01234567890123456789 does contain 0x0123456789012345, so that would be replaced with 6789.
To replace 0x<16-hex-digits> only if that's not followed by other hex digits, you could use perl instead:
perl -pe 's/0x[0-9a-f]{16}(?![0-9a-f])//gi'

Where (?!...) is a negative look ahead assertion operator generally not available in regexps supported by sed (ast-open's sed being an exception). In perl [0-9] only matches on 0123456789 and [a-f] abcdef regardless of the locale, but you can use [[:xdigit:]] there as well if you prefer.
More sed implementations support word boundary operators though the syntax varies between implementation:

\b like in perl
\<, \> like in ex/vi
[[:<:]], [[:>:]] on some BSDs

Some sed implementations also support a i or I flag to make the matching case insensitive like in perl. With GNU sed:
sed -E 's/0x[[:xdigit:]]{16}\b//gi'

Like:
perl -pe 's/0x[0-9a-f]{16}\b//gi'

Would remove the 0x<16-hex-digits> followed by a word boundary, that is provided what follows is not a word character (alnums or underscore).

¹ Initially neither basic nor extended regexps had \{x[,y]\} / {x[,y]} operators. \{...\} was added to BRE first and then {...} to ERE (pushed by POSIX) for consistency but often reluctantly as it was breaking backward compatibility (contrary to BREs where the behaviour for \{...\} was previously unspecified), and you'll find that some awk or egrep implementations still don't support it.
